# mysql-connector blocking on connection that is no longer there. Tomcat freezes

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tomcat6

We use JDBCRealm with mysql for form authentication in Tomcat. This works fine almost always.
When we stop/restart our mysql database (in test), we notice that one of the Tomcat HTTP threads will wait endlessly for some authentication related data, instead of failing (e.g. IOException or time out or something). This causes all other HTTP threads to block as well, as soon as they require a shared synchronized method. The result is that more and more HTTP threads are created, all blocking, until the maximum is reached.
The frozen thread never awakes or times out, even though I used netstat to confirm that the connection on which it is blocking, is effectively gone.
There is a firewall between both sides, although I don't think this has anything to do with the problem here. The connections are set up and taken down "normally".
Quick solution is ofcourse to stop/start tomcat with the database, but it seems odd that the call would not simply fail. Also I'm afraid this would happen in production in similar situations.
Is there something we can do other than restart tomcat or manually kill the blocking thread?
Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

The setup:

- tomcat6

  JDBCRealm for form authentication

  mysql 5.5 database

  mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar

relevant part of server.xml:

```
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" lockOutTime="300">
       <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
            connectionName="xxx"
            connectionPassword="xxx"
            connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://xxx:6446/xxx?autoReconnect=true"
            digest="xxx"
            driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            roleNameCol="xxx"
            userCredCol="xxx"
            userNameCol="xxx"
            userRoleTable="xxx"
            userTable="xxx"
            maxActive="30"
            maxIdle="30"
            maxWait="10000"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"/>
  </Realm>
```

Example of a blocked thread (blocking on entry of a "synchronized" method):

```
Name: http-8080-60
State: BLOCKED on org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm@edeb18b owned by: http-8080-61
Total blocked: 27  Total waited: 63

Stack trace: 
 org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:353)
org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:178)
org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate(LockOutRealm.java:196)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:260)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:454)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:394)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The single thread that is causing the blocks in all other threads (notice that the "available()" call is waiting/blocking on a connection that isn't there anymore):

```
Name: http-8080-61
State: RUNNABLE
Total blocked: 132  Total waited: 1,198

Stack trace: 
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAvailable(Native Method)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.available(Unknown Source)
   - locked java.net.SocksSocketImpl@c679aa4
java.net.SocketInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.available(ReadAheadInputStream.java:231)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.clearInputStream(MysqlIO.java:941)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1887)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2548)
   - locked java.lang.Object@65d98b58
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1560)
   - locked java.lang.Object@65d98b58
org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.getPassword(JDBCRealm.java:583)
   - locked org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm@edeb18b
org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:414)
   - locked org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm@edeb18b
org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:361)
   - locked org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm@edeb18b
org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:178)
org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate(LockOutRealm.java:196)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:260)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:454)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:394)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What's your Java version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try seting a read timeout on JDBC connection with `socketTimeout`.

```
jdbc:mysql://xxx:6446/xxx?autoReconnect=true&connectTimeout=60000&socketTimeout=60000
```

Comment: Thanks, this was nail on. It also helped me find [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) page which is very useful information that I didn't know of.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Database only for auth° ? Imho you should better use a datasource coupled with a `DataSourceRealm` and your `LockOutRealm`.
Maybe this last one is not well integrated with the `JDBCRealm`.

Here is a `JDBCRealm` javadoc extract :

`For a Realm implementation that supports connection pooling and doesn't require synchronisation of authenticate(), getPassword(), roles() and getPrincipal() or the ugly connection logic use the DataSourceRealm.`

Comment: Thanks we have meanwhile changed to DataSourceRealm, which has other benefits like being able to finely tune the connection pool settings. The JDBC connection parameters from the accepted answer work in both approaches.